# One child process with two parents

Tags: c, process, fork, pid

```
if (fork()==0)

{

printf("sup my name is %d" \

      " and my parent is %d",getpid(),getppid());}

printf("\n");

printf("pid %d-\n",getpid());

}
```

Why am i getting two different parents when I ran this?

[pid() and getppid()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hshl5.png)

Comment: From your linked image, you are not running the code you have posted. Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code, the output it generates, and the output you expect it to generate (ideally along with an explanation of why you expect that output), all directly included in the question (as text rather than an image). It may also help you (and will definitely help potential answerers) to properly indent the posted code to emphasize exactly which code is exclusive to the child process and which is executed in both the parent and the child.

Comment: Please post your full code. From the above code, I suspect that after you fork, the printf inside your if statement is running in child-process, and so its parent process id is returned. Exit the if statement, two printf statement will be run by the parent process itself. So if you get parent process id after exit the if, you will get grandparent process id. Check example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/).